# list contents of a server directory using JSP

Tags: jsp

I have files on server in following directory:

```
D:\tomcat8\webapps\schema_files\
```

I want to list all files present in above directory.

What I have tried

```
<%
String folder=application.getRealPath("D:/tomcat8/webapps/schema_files");
File file=new File(folder);
String fileNames[]=file.list();
System.out.println("fileNames[] : "+fileNames[0]);
%>
```

Its not working.

However if I store files in application itself at "/WEB-INF/filefolder" then following code works.

```
   <%
  String folder=application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/filefolder");
  File file=new File(folder);
  String fileNames[]=file.list();
  System.out.println("fileNames[] : "+fileNames[0]);
  %>
```

Please help me..

Comment: what does your program do for now? I mean what's the current output

Comment: @Dashovsky output is "java.lang.NullPointerException" at line "System.out.println("fileNames[] : "+fileNames[0]);"

Comment: is your program deployed to a .war file on your tomcat server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `application.getRealPath(String args0)` and `application.getContextPath()` pointing to your server directory like this:

```
File file=new  File(application.getRealPath(application.getContextPath())); 
String fileNames[]=file.list();
for(int i=0;i<fileNames.length;i++)
    System.out.println(fileNames[i]);
```

`application` is an implicit object available in JSP, just like `session` and `request`.

Comment: Where to pass directory path ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working, but there might be better approach which is explicit for JSP

```
<%
 File file=new File("D:\\tomcat8\\webapps\\schema_files");
 String fileNames[]=file.list();
 System.out.println("fileNames[] : "+fileNames[0]);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%=request.getContextPath()%>` can get you root path of your application so it's gonna be something like `localhost:port/yourappname`. Then all you need to do it's assign this to some other variable like string path and add your subfolder path or something.

Example:

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/folder1/folder2/webpage.html
```