# J2EE, ECLIPSE , Mysql , tomcat server

Tags: java

I have made a GUI with eclipse where i have used mysql as databasemanagment and tomcat as a server. 
I have some folder containig images that i need to link with my GUI.
How should I do it

Comment: What does it mean to link a folder with images to the GUI? You want to have those images available in your web app?

Comment: Yes . Basically My GUI is a bioinformatic  web application. So i have set of experiments that i store in the database. With them some images should also be stored so that i can view them. Its like uploading a whole directory of images and viewing them. How should i do it?

Comment: Reference an external file system/directory, or copy them into your project, or store them in the DB. I recommend the first.

Comment: To store them in the DB i need to give commands in DB and also in my GUI i need to write codes to connect with DB. May i know the codes?

Comment: You already interact with the DB, and how to store images in a DB is well-documented. But likely not recommended: file systems are a better place to store... files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691828/list-contents-of-a-server-directory-using-jsp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345647/list-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-a-folder-using-jsp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778525/want-to-display-file-list-using-jsp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947730/how-to-list-contents-of-a-server-directory-using-jsp) posts. All of them show how to list files from a directory using JSP (that will be deployed into tomcat).

Seems that you are a beginner. So, take a look into [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheTomcat/article.html) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_quick_guide.htm) tutorials related to jsp/tomcat.